# When using DISM to load drivers on an offline image, what driver version gets used if multiple versions are installed?

Tags: windows-10, dism, imaging

Does windows intelligently pick, is it the latest version, is it the last one (by order of installation) or does something else happen?

Answer (score 1):

DISM used this way will pick and install the latest Windows driver. The other drivers for the device will be ignored

Comment: Latest is newest by Date.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-the-driver-selection-process

> Windows uses the following criteria to select a driver for a device:
>
> Windows selects the driver that has the lowest rank value as the best match for the device.
>
> For drivers that have equal rank, Windows selects the driver that has the most recent date.
>
> For the drivers that have equal rank and date, Windows selects the driver that has the highest version.
>
> For drivers that have equal rank, date, and version, Windows can select any driver.